# Windows 7 Home Basic Installer: insffuicient privileges to modify "C:\Windows\Installer\." file

Tags: windows-7

I have been installing various downloaded programs on Windows 7 Home Basic. However, with Nokia PC Suite 7.1.60, I hit the above problem:

> The Installer has insufficient privilege to modify this file: "C:\Windows\Installer."

Yes, a 'dot' file in the directory!

I encounter a similar problem when attempting to install [SlimDrivers](http://www.driverupdate.net/). However, I have no problems with other software installations.

I've tried running as an administrator and changing the ownership to administrator, but no joy. Any ideas what's wrong, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Add the *Trusted Installer* account to the security tab of "%Windir%\Installer"

**edit**

Try the steps here to restore your security settings back to setup defaults.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949220

> Note This solution does not apply to Windows XP Home Edition, or
>   Windows Vista Home Basic and Home Premium editions. To restore
>   security settings for Home editions, you can use the Fix it, System
>   Restore, or a backup. Click Start, click Run, type cmd, and then press
>   ENTER. In Windows XP, type the following command, and then press
>   ENTER:  secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\repair\secsetup.inf /db
>   secsetup.sdb /verbose
>
> In Windows Vista, type the following command, and then press ENTER: 
>   secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb
>   /verbose
>
> You receive a "Task is completed" message and a warning message that
>   something could not be done. You can safely ignore this message. For
>   more information about this message, see the
>   %windir%\Security\Logs\Scesrv.log file. Next steps After you run this
>   Microsoft Fix it (or complete these manual steps), standard user
>   accounts may no longer appear on the log on screen when you start your
>   computer or try to switch users. This occurs because standard user
>   accounts are removed from the Users group when you reset Windows
>   security settings. To add the affected users accounts back to the
>   Users group, follow these steps: Click Start, and then All Programs.
>   Or click Programs. Click Accessories, and then click Command Prompt
>   (Windows XP). Or right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run As
>   Administrator (Windows Vista). In the Command Prompt window, type net
>   users and then press ENTER. A list of user accounts is displayed. For
>   each accountname listed in the Command Prompt that is missing from the
>   log on or switch user screen, type the following command and then
>   press ENTER:
>
> net localgroup users accountname /add Now go to the "Did this fix the
>   problem?" section. Note In Windows Vista, the Defltbase.inf file is a
>   Security configuration template for the default security. You can view
>   the settings for this file in the following location:
>   %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf
>
> For online Help about Secedit, click Start, click Run, type
>   %windir%\help\secedit.chm, and then press ENTER.

Definitely click the link and try the fixit tool first.

Comment: Added as suggested but now with more serious problem! The installer service does not start. Tried with Services.msc, it gives error 5. Have also attempted msiexec /unregister and msiexec /regserver with hard reboot, still no joy. Please help!

Comment: Added as suggested but now with more serious problem!

Comment: Furthermore, I could not find the installer folder to revert back!

Comment: Changing the ownership to Administrator usually makes it worse, because the different services run with different accounts and thus different privileges to prevent malware from going bananas on your computer.  I'll have to find the link that resets security settings back to setup defaults.

Comment: Many thanks, I have managed to restored. I am using Windows 7 Home Basic. What is peculiar are on these 2 programs I have the the problem, at this stage and really like to have them installed. I do have Windows 7 Ultimate, can I merely upgrade Home Basic to Ultimate?

Comment: You can use Windows Anytime Upgrade. As long as they are the same architecture (x86 upgrade to x86 OR  x64 upgrade x64.) Otherwise you'll need to reinstall.

Comment: Hello Surfasb. Have upgraded successfully to Windows 7 Ultimate. After adding Trusted Installer account to the security tab of "%Windir%\Installer" - it works!   Do I need to remove Trusted Installer?

Comment: Nope. You should leave that. The trusted installer is pretty secure. It's one(well it is in more than one spot) of those files that Windows keeps a copy of and, when it notices some rogue program that overwrites it, Windows just restores the old copy.  That's pretty rare these days because of UAC though.